# Objective C - Error with custom return type?

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to Objective-C, so this is probably very basic.

Anyhow, I am trying to specify a custom return type in my class, and I keep getting errors that the class either needs an asterisk* or is not considered a type at all. I read that you need to use @class instead of #import in your header files, but that doesn't seem to help in this case. What else am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Room;

@interface LevelData : NSObject {

@private

    NSArray *data;
    Room *currentRoom;

}

+(void)initialize;
+(*Room)getCurrentRoom;

@end
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Of note, typically — well, those following [Apple's coding style](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) — you'd name it `currentRoom` as opposed to `getCurrentRoom`.  But this is just convention.  Only setter methods have the 'set' prefix (i.e.: `setCurrentRoom:`).  You could argue that it's because you're only reading a value and not performing any action, thus, not requiring any verb.  But if you start this habit, you'll be better off in the long run with Key-Value Coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that one line to:

```
+(Room *)getCurrentRoom;
```

and see if that compiles.  `Room *` indicates you're returning a pointer to a Room Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

1. The asterisk should go after the class name, like a standard C-style
   pointer.
2. Class methods should return a value,
   usually a pointer to an object of the same class, so if you do use
   `initialize` you'll want it to return a `Room*`.
3. Good coding practice is to override `-(Class *) init;`, but
   only if you need to. This is because the first thing you (or someone
   else using your code) should/will do when using an object (usually)
   is to call some form of `[[Class alloc] init]`. If they call this
   when you have a special `initialize` function, it will call the
   `NSObject` `-(NSObject *)init;` method instead, and your instance
   variables won't get setup.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is init a constructor or just standard practice?

Comment: +(void)initialize is special, and you should not call it yourself.  It is called by the runtime once when your class is loaded and can be used to initialize class-wide data (akin to Java class static variables).  It's a complex topic, but in general, anything you would use +(void)initialize for could arguably be done better another way (like with a singleton or dispatch_once or whatever...). If you're calling +(void)initialize yourself you are most likely doing it wrong.